# Location of android wakelock c code for android, or hardware/power.h file

Tags: android, android-wake-lock

I'm trying to implement wakelock in C/cpp.. I assume there's a bit of c code that sits under the java call, and when I look at the wakelock in the com_android_server_power_PowerManagerService, I see what looks like a good bit of code.. But it of course sits on code I can't find.  The hardware/power.h file.

So my question.  Does anyone know where to find the hardware/power.h file.  I don't see it in the android source.. Perhaps I'm missing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Android XRef](http://androidxref.com/source/xref/hardware/libhardware/include/hardware/power.h), `power.h` is in `/hardware/libhardware/include/hardware/power.h`, which then resides [at this spot in the Git Web interface for the AOSP](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/libhardware/+/master/include/hardware/power.h).